# How to get all css properties and events of a html element with jquery or other libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

see these pictures :
[image]

How to get all corresponding css properties of a specific html element with their current values and events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getComputedStyle()`

```js
var body = $('body')[0];
var style = window.getComputedStyle(body, null);
var events = $._data(body, "events");

console.log(style)
console.log(events);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @dan-phlip , What about events ?